# How can one select an attribute with a Windows-format path in a CSS rule?

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code, css-selectors, customization

I am looking to style some elements in VS Code (but really could be any web app, Electron/NWjs-based app, Neutralino-based app, etc, anything that has a webview and can enumerate a filesystem) based on an element attribute that contains their absolute path but it's Windows formatted. Example:

```
<li data-path="C:\Windows\System32\etc">
  <a href="#">/etc</a>
</li>
```

as

`li[data-path="C\:\\Windows\\System32\\etc"]`

In JavaScript I've attempted to select it using `Element.querySelector` with `CSS.escape` but attempting to use the whole path fails and I essentially have to programmatically generate a usable rule by splitting on backslash and making a super-specific selector like:

```
li[data-path^="C\:"]
  [data-path*="Windows"]
  [data-path*="System32"]
  [data-path*="etc"]
```

Not only does that look terrible it also could easily match the wrong item:

```
<li data-path="C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\some-extra-folder\some-folder-with-the-word-etc\etc">
  <a href="#">/etc</a>
</li>
```

Is there some working method to generate a valid CSS attribute selector for such a string?

If possible I'd prefer to avoid using 3rd-party libraries like jQuery to minimize dependencies, but if something like Sizzle.js or other CSS querySelector-like implementation is the absolute only way to get a working attribute selector function I'll use if absolutely necessary.

Currently I'm using `document.querySelectorAll('li[data-path]')` and looping through and raw-comparing the string values while I'm still looking for a CSS attribute selector that actually works for Windows-style paths.

*Edit: adding the HTML that VS Code actually generates for a file in its Explorer view*

```html
<div class="monaco-list-row focused selected" role="treeitem" data-index="16" data-last-element="false" aria-setsize="8" aria-posinset="5" id="list_id_4_16" aria-label="app.js" aria-level="3" draggable="true" style="top: 352px; height: 22px; line-height: 22px;" aria-selected="true">
  <div class="monaco-tl-row">
    <div class="monaco-tl-indent" style="width: 40px;">
      <div class="indent-guide" style="width: 16px"></div>
      <div class="indent-guide active" style="width: 16px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="monaco-tl-twistie" style="padding-left: 40px;"></div>
    <div class="monaco-tl-contents">
      <div class="monaco-icon-label file-icon app.js-name-file-icon js-ext-file-icon ext-file-icon javascript-lang-file-icon explorer-item" title="C:\Users\liqui\Documents\dev\neu-lx-dash\app\assets\app.js" style="display: flex;">
        <div class="monaco-icon-label-container">
          <span class="monaco-icon-name-container">
            <a class="label-name">
              <span class="monaco-highlighted-label" title="C:\Users\liqui\Documents\dev\neu-lx-dash\app\assets\app.js">
                <span>app.js</span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </span>
          <span class="monaco-icon-description-container"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @MisterJojo ! Breaking up the text any further would not only result in basically one "paragraph" per sentence, but would also essentially break up the sentences and make them even less understandable fragments.

Comment: Hi @NelsonTeixeira ! *Technically* I'm not new here, but it certainly has been a long time since I've posted and if there are any particular formatting guidelines that I could follow to make it more understandable please feel free to let me know!

Comment: Hope it's better now. Feel free to roll back my edition if you think I edited anything inapropriately

Comment: The current edits look fine and still convey what I'm looking to ask, thanks!

Comment: you can say that I am there for at least 3/4, while English is not my native language and that I have to translate everything constantly

Comment: @MisterJojo  That's ok; basically I've given examples of elements with data attributes that show filesystem paths and would like to validly select them in JS using CSS attribute selectors. Since the paths are Windows-formatted in this case the strings need to have special chars escaped first.

VS Code actually populates the `title` attribute of the relevant elements with the file path, but otherwise the examples show the primary use case.

Comment: Added VS Code generated HTML for context. Looking to CSS target the `.monaco-icon-label` with the specific file path as its title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a solution!

[I asked the CSSWG on GitHub](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4820) and in JavaScript at least the escaped attribute needs to be run through the [`String.raw` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/string/raw) to further solidify the escape. The example given was as follows (uses `Element.matches` and manually escapes, but also does indeed work for `Element.querySelector` and/or with `CSS.escape` results):

```js
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.dataset.path = String.raw`c:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe`;
li.matches(String.raw`li[data-path^="c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint.exe"]`); // true
li.matches(String.raw`li[data-path^=c\:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint\.exe]`); // true
```

Huzzah! Will require a properly ES6-compatible browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is a service for Regex. Unfortunatelly AFAIK there is no such thing as a regex selector for CSS. But if you instead of doing in directly in CSS you could run some js, it makes things much easier as you can filter elements using regex. Here's an example:

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-path]');

var windowsPathRegEx = /[A-Z]\:\\.*/

var winLis = [...lis].filter(
        li=>li.dataset.path.match(windowsPathRegEx)
    );

console.log(winLis);
```

```html
<li id='a' data-path="C:\Windows\System32\etc">
  <a href="#">li with windows path</a>
</li>
<li id='b' no-data>
  <a href="#">li without path</a>
</li>
<li id='c' data-path="C:\Program Files\whatever">
  <a href="#">another li with windows path</a>
</li>
<li id='d' data-path="/usr/local/share">
  <a href="#">li with linux path</a>
</li>
```

Just develop an adequate regex for your needs and you're ready to go.

I don't use VSCode, but I imagine that if it's stylable, there should be some kind of js initialization where you can put this code.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing  except comparing raw strings in the filter rather than matching a regexp because I'm looking to find the singular path rather than all items that match `[data-path]`.

The use case in VS Code (using the Custom CSS & JS extension) is as such: set a MutationObserver on the tabs on top so any that become "dirty" or get saved trigger it; observer CSS selects the given file in the Explorer list on the side; if found it adds/removes a "dirty" class to/from the given item.

Currently VS Code does not mark files in sidebar as dirty, only tabs and Open Editors.

Comment: I've updated the question to include VS Code generated HTML for context. Looking to CSS target the `.monaco-icon-label` with the specific file path as its title.

Comment: I don't think there's another way to do it.